# Response too large error calling BigQuery from GoogleSheets AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

Am scripting an aggregate query that gets executed from a script in a GoogleSheets document - the result set will be less than 50k rows (ie not large) and runs in just under a minute. I am using that to populate a Data sheet which will then be used to derive a pivot table.

However when I execute the script I get:

```
Exception: Response Code: 413. Message: response too large.
```

I've searched for info about this and can find various references to getting the data into another *table* but I need that volume of data to be loaded into a spreadsheet for ongoing analysis.

Am I hitting a hard limit trying to do this in GoogleSheets?

TIA, M